# Kivy, Mask Widget Canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I find myself using ScatterLayout a lot (Scatter inside of Scatter and so on...). One feature that escapes me is applying some kind of alpha mask to a Scatter canvas. The idea would be to perform simple shape knockouts that correspond to a background image or other simple depth tricks.

I feel like this is doable with some basic OpenGL or maybe the *kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions*. I am not particularly comfortable with heavy OpenGL commands (I don't know how to debug them), but wrapping some simple commands into a Widget Class is just fine.

So here is what I am getting from other sources, but I want to take this beyond primitive solids (like Rectangle):

**Updated with a texture based direction (code is untested!)**

```
    with self.canvas:

        # Hopefully I can build my "transparency mask" manually with a Texture
        texture = Texture.create(size=(64, 64))
        size = 64 * 64 * 3
        buf = [int(x * 255 / size) for x in range(size)]
        buf = b''.join(map(chr, buf))
        texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        StencilPush()

        Rectangle(texture=texture, pos=self.pos, size=(64, 64))

        #use mask
        StencilUse()

        """
        Will we get an image based mask on all drawing commands placed here?
        """

        StencilPop()
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802203/how-do-i-mask-an-image-in-kivy-using-python)?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Your post did bring up new ideas but have not tested yet. I edited my question to reflect my updated thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MultiTexture Canvas](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__canvas__multitexture__py.html) is exactly the answer. Try using your own custom PNG and you will see, make them as complex as you like and it works beautifully. I am going to include the important pieces of code that make it work, and consider the question Answered, although I may yet reopen if I run into rendering order problems (since I am not using a static PNG for my application.

The very simple shader definition you need to include as a docstring (it will be autoloaded, see the link above if I have stripped this too far:

```
fs_multitexture = '''
$HEADER$

// New uniform that will receive texture at index 1
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main(void) {

    // multiple current color with both texture (0 and 1).
    // currently, both will use exactly the same texture coordinates.
    gl_FragColor = frag_color * \
        texture2D(texture0, tex_coord0) * \
        texture2D(texture1, tex_coord0);
}
'''
```

And a bare minimum Widget class that demonstrates the texture filtering process that creates this simple magic:

```
class MultitextureWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = RenderContext()
        self.canvas.shader.fs = fs_multitexture
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 1)
            BindTexture(source='mtexture2.png', index=1)
            Rectangle(size=(150, 150), source='mtexture1.png', pos=(500, 200))

        self.canvas['texture1'] = 1
        super(MultitextureWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 0)

    def update_glsl(self, *largs):
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = Window.render_context['projection_mat']
        self.canvas['modelview_mat'] = Window.render_context['modelview_mat']
```